# Unbind service in android.app.Application

Tags: java, android

In the application in `onCreate()` I bind to `InAppBillingService`. There is no `onDestroy()` method in the `Application` class.

How to implement the call to `unbindService()` after the application is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is not the best approach. It is not a good practice to this because this way your service will live as long as your application which is not the best scenario.

My advice is to use the binding in a concrete activity. This way you can unbind when the activity is paused and rebind when it is resumed. If you need to bind in more than one activities, create a super class that does this and extend it with your concrete activity classes.

If you need a service that will run through the whole application's life, the right approach is to use a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). It has the highest priority so it won't be killed first when the OS starts to free resources. The other benefit of this approach is that this way your application lives as long as your service but not the opposite. The control of the lifetime is in the `Service` but not in the application which is the right way.

Comment: Remember that the `InAppBillingService` in this case is part of Google Play Services and the user is a client. The OP is not writing the service and hence the only thing the OP has under his control is the timing of binding and unbinding to this "always running", "always present" service. So, i would side with @Karakuri on his answer in this regard.

Comment: I ended up using this lib for billing https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 But I used the ideas from your answer by creating the service only in the activities where I need billing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the Application object is destroyed, then your service should also be destroyed. You cannot have one of your application components running without an instance of your Application object.

If you prefer to explicitly unbind from the service, you can have your Activities bind to it in `onStart` and unbind from it in `onStop` instead.

Comment: It is better to use ```onPause``` and ```onResume``` methods. There is no need the ```Service``` to be bound to the ```Activity``` while the ```Activity``` is paused.

Comment: I use `onStart` and `onStop` specifically to prevent the service being destroyed when transitioning from one Activity to another. If you do it in `onPause` and `onResume`, then there is a window where the Service is not bound and will be destroyed, and then the next `onResume` has to create it again. If you use `onStart` and `onStop`, then if moving between two activities that both bind to the Service, there is no window where the Service is unbound.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in this case your service will be destroyed when your first activity that bound to the service is removed from the stack and destroyed. I don't think you are doing it right. If you want to run your service through several activities it is better first to start it (```startActivity```) instead of just bind to it. This way you will have the control to stop it when you want, not relying on the destruction of the first activity that bound to the service. So let's say you have 2 activities and 1 service.

Comment: So let's say you have 2 activities that bind to a single service in their ```onCreate``` methods and unbind in their ```onDestroy```methods. This way your service will be destroyed when both of your activities are destroyed. If you use ```startService``` in combination with binding and unbinding in ```onResume``` and ```onPause``` methods, you will be able to stop the service in any point of the execution of your program.

Comment: I have verified that if I want my service to be running only as long as one of my Activities is in the foreground, then the method I described does exactly this. You can certainly also start and stop the service explicitly, but is sounds like there isn't a clear place that the OP wants to do so, hence I suggested my approach.

Comment: I am not saying that your approach is not working. I am saying that this way you lose the control over the service's life. You leave activities bound to the service and the control is taken by the activity stack - when all of your bound activities are destroyed then your service will be destroyed :)

Comment: **That's the point.** He doesn't want explicit control of the life of his service, he wants it to run only as long as something is using it, which is exactly what bound services are for. If he wants explicit control of its lifecycle, then he should start and stop the service explicitly.

Comment: `InAppBillingService` is not a service the OP wrote. He/she is just a client of the service. So, all he can do is bind/unbind based on his needs.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's documentation at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service:

> Important: Remember to unbind from the In-app Billing service when
>   you are done with your Activity. If you don’t unbind, the open service
>   connection could cause your device’s performance to degrade. This
>   example shows how to perform the unbind operation on a service
>   connection to In-app Billing called mServiceConn by overriding the
>   activity’s onDestroy method.

That means that having the service bind to the Application object is a bad idea, since it will be eating resources the entire time your application is running. Instead bind to an Activity or a Fragment and then unbind in their onDestroy method.